# request.getParameter not working

Tags: java, servlets

I have developed a file download program, which is implemented by Java Servlet. 
The link sent to the user is in the following format:
http://examples.com/file?id=6565_1_1_1_201110

When user clicks this link, it will send a request to a servlet program to find the file name and then download the file. In the servlet I use the following code to retrieve the id value:

```
String param = "";
synchronized (this) {
    param = request.getParameter("id");
}
```

Now the problem is, some users can get the correct value, which is 6565_1_1_1_201110. However, some users have obtained the wrong value, like 656543_1_1_1_20111067, etc, which is not fixed. I do not know where are those additional number from? 
Any idea on this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending what you think you are? Also, if `this` is referencing the `Servlet`, that's a bad idea.

Comment: This is most probably not a problem related to request parameter, but to link generator.

Comment: From the log file, when a user clicks the link, it has obtained the wrong value for the first click. Then user would try again and it works fine. So this may not be the link problem. I am using the Tomcat server. Is this related to any character encoding issue? And advice on a better way to implement this?